# What happens if two distinct processes use mmap to map the same region of file (one with MAP_SHARED, another with MAP_PRIVATE)?

Tags: c++, c, mmap

Can two distinct(not parent/child) processes use mmap to map the same region of file, the process A with flag MAP_SHARED, the process B with MAP_PRIVATE)?
If process A changes something in the region, can the process B see it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a MAP\_PRIVATE handle changes to the underlying file after mmap() is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632724/how-does-a-map-private-handle-changes-to-the-underlying-file-after-mmap-is-cal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then A gets the file mapped and B gets the file mapped but any writes will not be written back to the file.

From the manpage:

> It is  unspecified  whether changes made to the file after the mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.