# If I private-`mmap` a file and read it, then another process writes to the same file, will another read at the same location return the same value?

Tags: linux, posix, race-condition, mmap

(Context: I'm trying to establish which sequences of `mmap` operations are safe from the "memory safety" point of view, i.e. what assumptions I can make about `mmap`ed memory without risking security bugs as a consequence of undefined behaviour, or miscompiles due to compilers making incorrect assumptions about how memory could behave. I'm currently working on Linux but am hoping to port the program to other operating systems in the future, so although I'm primarily interested in Linux, answers about how other operating systems behave would also be appreciated.)

Suppose I map a portion into file into memory using `mmap` with `MAP_PRIVATE`. Now, assuming that the file doesn't change while I have it mapped, if I access part of the returned memory, I'll be given information from the file at that offset; and (because I used `MAP_PRIVATE`) if I write to the returned memory, my writes will persist in my process's memory but will have no effect on the underlying file.

However, I'm interested in what will happen if the file *does* change while I have it mapped (because some other process also has the file open and is writing to it). There are several cases that I know the answers to already:

- If I map the file with `MAP_SHARED`, then if any other process writes to the file via a shared `mmap`, my own process's memory will also be updated. (This is the intended behaviour of `MAP_SHARED`, as one of its intended purposes is for shared-memory concurrency.) It's less clear what will happen if another process writes to the file via other means, but I'm not interested in that case.
- If the following sequence of events occurs:

  1. I map the file with `MAP_PRIVATE`;
  2. A portion of the file I haven't accessed yet is written by another process;
  3. I read that portion of the file via my mapping;

  then, at least on Linux, the read might return either the old value or the new value:

  > It is unspecified  whether changes made to the file after the mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.
  > — **man 2 mmap** on Linux

  (This case – which is not the case I'm asking about – is covered in [this existing StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50632724/11875845).)

  I also checked the POSIX definition of `mmap`, but (unless I missed it) it doesn't seem to cover this case at all, leaving it unclear whether all POSIX systems would act the same way.

  Linux's behaviour makes sense here: at the time of the access, the kernel might have already mapped the requested part of the file into memory, in which case it doesn't want to change the portion that's already there, but it might need to load it from disk, in which case it will see any new value that may have been written to the file since it was opened. So there are performance reasons to use the new value in some cases and the old value in other cases.
- If the following sequence of events occurs:

  1. I map the file with `MAP_PRIVATE`;
  2. I write to a memory address within the file mapping;
  3. Another process changes that part of the file;

  then although I don't know this for certain, I think it's very likely that the rule is that the memory address in question continues to reflect the old value, that was written by our process. The reason is that the kernel needs to maintain two copies of that part of the file anyway: the values as seen by our process (which, because it used `MAP_PRIVATE`, can write to its view of the file without changing the underlying file), and the values that are actually in the file on disk. Writes by other processes obviously need to change the second copy here, so it would be bizarre to also change the first copy; doing so would make the interface less usable and also come at a performance cost, and would have no advantages.

There is one sequence of events, though, where I don't know what happens (and for which the behaviour is hard to determine experimentally, given the number of possible factors that might be relevant):

1. I map the file with `MAP_PRIVATE`;
2. I read some portion of the file via the mapping, without writing;
3. Another process changes part of the file that I just read;
4. I read the same portion of the file via the mapping, again.

In this situation, am I guaranteed to read the same data twice? Or is it possible to read the old data the first time and the new data the second time?

Comment: The reason for the unspecified case is not because of reading from disk, because Linux has uses shared file buffers. It's to handle network file systems, since the server doesn't notify the clients when some other process modifies the file.

Comment: MAP_PRIVATE is based on copy-on-write. When you modify a page, you get your own copy of that page, and it's no longer linked to the original file. So your changes aren't written to the file, and other process's changes to that page are not seen by you.

Comment: I'm aware that `MAP_PRIVATE` is based on copy-on-write, but that doesn't actually answer the question – it's unclear from the documentation whether the copy is triggered by *this process* writing to the mapped memory or *any process* writing to the portion of the file that is mapped; and there are potential corner cases like "my process read this part of the file, but the memory subsequently got swapped out" which could plausibly swap the memory back onto the original file rather than into the swap file if it were unmodified, meaning that the page would apparently not have multiple references.

Comment: Swapping in/out is irrelevant; we're dealing with virtual memory, it doesn't matter if it's in RAM or disk. When this process makes a change, it makes a local copy that's backed by swap space instead of the original file.

Comment: What happens if another process makes a change is unspecified, as stated in the second bullet.